# How to update data continuously in application without calling APIs after some interval of time?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to know how I can update data in my iOS App continuously without calling APIs time by time. Like for example, if I have a product list in my tableView and I want to update price of every products from server because it changes continuously.

Is there any way, I can make any event from server that can be detected in my application when any value in server is changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes use push notification (Silent).

Comment: Not an expert, but maybe look up "sockets"?

Comment: Have a look at reactive programming like RXSwift which will actually serve your purpose. But the server side also should be in reactive way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the approaches in iOS to constantly update data coming from some server.

1. ## Polling

   Polling is term used to constantly request server using some `POST` or `GET` request after regular or irregular interval of time.
2. ## Push-Notification

   `Silent Push-Notification` is an approach to update data whenever changes occurs. In this type server generates and request **Apple** to send a notification with some custom `JSON`. This is fast but **Non-Guaranteed** approach. Because `Push` can be miss some time or can be delay some time.
3. ## Socket

   `Socket` is the most reliable and accurate solution for such issues in which an application needs to update their `client-end` whenever changes occurs on their `back-end`. Because it always keeps a live communication with server so you do-not need to request server every time.

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario you want to update every cell value . using Socket programming you can achieve that. socket programming help to fast and real time update date.

Socket programming reference :

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/157128/real-time-communication-streams-tutorial-ios

Comment: can this socket programming can be done in objective-c?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a frequent "push" of data from your server, you can use technologies like or [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [HTTP long polling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6202) (which kind of simulates a push through polling).

The [Socket.IO-Client-Swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) library abstracts the details of those and provides a nice interface for the app.

Using plain old TCP sockets is the 3rd alternative.

I assume here that your update rate is on the order of every 10 minutes or quicker (up to dozens of seconds). If you have your updates less frequently, like hourly, then [Apple Push (aka remote) notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html) should work as well.